# Group and Ring Homomorphisms between $\mathbb{Z}_p$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{2p}$

Tags: group-theory, ring-theory, finite-groups, abstract-algebra

Let $p$ be prime with $p > 2$.

(a) Determine the number of group homomorphisms between $\mathbb{Z}_p$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{2p}$

(b) Determine the number of ring homomorphisms between $\mathbb{Z}_p$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{2p}$

This is what i understand so far thank to everyone here. So for part (a), if $$\varphi: \mathbb{Z}_p \longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{2p}$$ is a homomorphism. I first think that $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is cyclic, so $\mathbb{Z}_p = \langle1\rangle$, but as a relation in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ we must have that $p\cdot1=0$. So to know all the homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}_p \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{2p}$, I send the element $1 \in \mathbb{Z}_p $ to an element $x \in \mathbb{Z}_{2p}$, but the element $x$ must satisfy $p\cdot x=0$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{2p}$. In other words, we have that $p\cdot x=0$ mod $(2p)$. Now this condition implies that $2p \mid px$, but since $p$ is prime then $2 \nmid p \Rightarrow 2 \mid x$, therefore i can send the element $1 \in \mathbb{Z}_p $ to all the even numbers in $\mathbb{Z}_{2p}$, that is $0,2,4, \ldots , 2p-2$ and we thus have exactly $p$ homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ to $\mathbb{Z}_{2p}$.

Comment: Group and ring homomorphisms from $\Bbb Z_p$ are determined by the number of places you can send $1$. So count them.

Comment: Does your definition of a ring homomorphism require $1$ to be sent to $1$?

Comment: $\mathbb Z_n$ is always cyclic (and generated by $1$ modulo $n$), no matter whether $n$ is prime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint for (a):** Let $\phi\colon\mathbb Z_p \to \mathbb Z_{2p}$ be a homomorphism.  As $p = 0$ in $\mathbb Z_p$ we have $p\cdot\phi(1) = \phi(p) = \phi(0) = 0$.  What elements $x \in \mathbb Z_{2p}$ satisfy $p\cdot x = 0$?  If $\phi(1) = x$ then show that $\phi$ is defined by $\phi(a) = a\cdot x$ (use induction).

**Hint for (b):** A ring homomorphism is, in particular, a group homomorphism of the additive structure, so look at the homomorphisms you got in part (a) and check which of them satisfy the additional axioms for ring homomorphisms.

Comment: @JimI not getting the part on what elements $x \in \mathbb Z_{2p}$ satisfy $p\cdot x = 0$, On the other hand for induction would be something like this: If $\phi(1) = x$, for $a=1$, its clear, so we assume its true for $a=k$. Now, for $a=k+1$, we have: $\phi(k+1) = (k+1)x = kx+x = k\phi(1) + \phi(1) = \phi(k) + \phi(1)$

Comment: For the induction $a$ is fixed and you are inducting on $x$.  You want to conclude with $\phi(k + 1) = (k + 1)x$, it appears as though you concluded with $\phi(k + 1) = \phi(k) + \phi(1)$.

Comment: Do you know the condition for a number to be equivalent to zero in $\mathbb Z_{2p}$?

Comment: @JimSo, a number is equivalent to zero in $\mathbb Z_{2p}$, if the remainder, when the number is divided by $2p$, is zero, right...On the other hand, for the induction would be: $\phi(k+1) = (k+1)\phi(1)$, but $\phi(1) = x \Rightarrow \phi(k+1) = (k+1)\phi(1) = (k+1)x$, Im not getting the idea clear in this exercise

Comment: For the induction I was thinking $\phi(k + 1) = \phi(k) + \phi(1) = a\cdot k + a\cdot 1 = a\cdot(k + 1)$, but I guess you're right, you don't really need that, $\phi(k + 1) = (k + 1)\phi(1)$ works.

Comment: Ok, so $px = 0$ in $\mathbb Z_{2p}$ means $2p$ divides $px$, what does this mean about $x$?

Comment: @Jim...Well if $2p|px$ since $2 \nmid p \Rightarrow 2|x$, thats the only thing that i have in mind

Comment: That's it, the $x \in \mathbb Z_{2p}$ that satisfy $px = 0$ are exactly the even numbers $0, 2, 4, \ldots, 2p - 2$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19094/discussion-between-ricardo-cervantes-and-jim).

Comment: @Jim...So, if $\phi\colon\mathbb Z_p \to \mathbb Z_{2p}$ is a homomorphism, given by $\phi(a) = a\cdot x$, then the number of group homomorphism would be $p$, because there are $p$ elements in $\mathbb Z_{2p}$ that satisfy $px = 0$, which they are $0, 2, 4, \ldots, 2p - 2$